# Get _correct_ coordinates of user MapKit on simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mapkit

the situation is following, i am running xCode 4.1 on MacOS 10.7, starting iPhone simulator and using MapKit am trying to get **REAL** user's coordinates ... default user's location is in Cupertino, USA ... to get cordinates of this point i use :

```
self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate
```

... but this gets me to the center of the map (in Africa) ...

**Question #1 :** Why??? Why user's pin is set to Cupertino but its coordinates are (lat:0, lon:0) in Africa?

... then ...

I have setup my controller as CCLocationManagerDelegate and MKMapViewdelegate and initialized controller as delegate for CCLocationManagerDelegate's events ... but neither of these delegate methods was called ...

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```

**Question #2 :** Why delegate methods are not triggered even once?

My controller :

```
//@interface MapController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate> 

//@property (nonatomic, retain) MapModel *mapModel;
//@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{ ... }

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{ ... }

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{ ... }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapModel = [[[MapModel alloc] init:self] autorelease];

    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    [self.mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [self.mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D x = 
        self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate; // (0,0) why???

    //[self.mapView setRegion:xx animated:YES];
    //[self.mapView regionThatFits:self.mapModel.region];
    [[self.mapView userLocation] setCoordinate:[x coordinate]];
}

...
```

And model :

```
   //@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *user;
   //@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *caption;
   //@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *description;
   //@property (nonatomic, assign) MKCoordinateRegion region;
   //@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *manager;

    - (id)init :(id)delegate
    {
        self.manager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];

        self.manager.delegate = delegate;
        self.manager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        self.manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        [self.manager startUpdatingLocation];

        MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0, 0}, {0.2, 0.2}};

        self.region = region;

        return self;
    }
```

Thanks, Art

Comment: if `self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate` gives you 0,0 it is probably because mapView or userLocation or location is a nil pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default location in the simulator is Cupertino.  In the latest Xcode (4.2, I believe), you can set the location of the simulator from a menu of prepopulated locations (to which you can add your own simply by including a GPX file in your project).

If you run on the device AND ENABLE LOCATION SERVICES FOR THE APP, you should get a valid location using your code.

Comment: ok, i understand that Cupertino is preset location but why blue user's mark is in Cupertino and mapView.userLocation is in Africa ? Why they are different?

Comment: @Art check to see if the mapView.userLocation is `nil` or not.

Comment: I don't have an answer for that.  Have you tried either on the device or in Xcode 4.2 (setting the location to something non-Cupertino)?

Comment: What @XcodeDev said. I think the simulator doesn't "enable" Location Services prior to Xcode 4.2 and thus you're getting a nil location (even though it shows the location in CUP).

Comment: it is not null ... at first call userLocation is following - latitude:2.9960885786808235e-282, longitude:1.6178140217591351e-303 then i set mapView parameters (including showUserLocation) and get following values on second call - latitude:2.5498006923989488e-301, longitude:1.2256803803597691e-282 ...

Comment: @Art, have you tried running on a device or Xcode 4.2 yet? Also, MKMapView's userLocation is a readonly property.  Not sure that setting the coordinate of the userLocation is actually going to work.

Comment: nope, i am NOT trying to change user's location (and i know that real user's location is not movable), i just want to focus / zoom map on place where the user is now (e.g. on Cupertino) ... and for this i need to get his coordinates programmatically ... which seem to be wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify my question ...
As far as i understand userLocation seems to be nil on simulator anyway ... ok ... but second question is why CLLocationManagerDelegate method "didUpdateToLocation" is not called?
I saw this tutorial and it should be called even on simulator ...
So what am i doing wrong?
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNMNRAbIDoU&feature=related
Meanwhile i get such error in Log - "server did not accept client registration 68"
Can this be the reason why location delegate is not called?

**UPDATE :**

I tried this on xCode 4.3 and it still does not work...
At first call to userLocation it returns (0,0) at second - (-180,-180)

Then i switched to IOS 5 SDK and now Map is not loading at all with error - `__GEORegisterNetworkDefaults_block_invoke_0: Could not connect to geod on com.apple.geod.defaults`

**UPDATE :**

Uninstall of all xCode version and then installation of stable 4.2 version did help ... **Resolved!!!**

Comment: Good information.  BTW, if you eventually go to install Xcode 4.3 beta, be sure to install it in a *separate* directory from your 4.2 installation.